# how to remove previous views in ViewWillApear?

Tags: iphone, ipad, viewwillappear

I have TabBarController in app, so all tab bar items are loading at same time,,

when I am update data, and coming back, then previous views are still there and new views are added above them

what should I do

my Coding is in ViewWillApear,

I haven't code in ViewDidLoad because I want to see data as I update them in database,

and ViewDidLoad is being called once, but ViewWillApear is being called everytime, 
so everytime new views are added and previous are there,,,,

hope you understand what I mean,,,

Comment: if you are coming from that view u can remove that in viewwilldisapper method.

Comment: @Fasttracks, What should I write in ViewWillDisAppear?

Comment: [self.view removeAllSubViews];, I tried it, but no use :-(

Comment: in viewdidunload method write myoutlet=nil;

Comment: I have done all coding manually, not using Interface Builder, so ?

Answer (score 0):

You want the values displayed by those views or you want to update the views in all.

If you want to update only values, then do that in viewWillAppear: no need to create and add the whole views again. Its not good practice.

Create the views once only in loadView or viewDidLoad: method. and assign them values in viewWillAppear:

or else in your

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    [self removeAllSubviews];

    //OR
    for(UIView * view in self.view.subviews)
    {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
            view = nil;
    }

}
```

Comment: like only one line code in ViewWillApear, as [name_label setText:name-var];

Comment: hey, I am not assigning values one time, but I am update sqlite3 database and retrieving data from their, so each time I have new values which I have updated, you got ?

Comment: yes, so whats the problem, everytime when ViewWIllApppear: will get called, updated values will be set.